# WPF MVVM DataGridComboboxColumn change one row updates all

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've got a datagrid in my view. One of the columns is a datagridcomboboxcolumn which itemsource is bound to a list in my view model through a static resource. The problem is that when I change the selected item in one row, the same item is selected on the other rows.

View Model

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   private ObservableCollection<Wavelength> wlList = new ObservableCollection<Wavelength>();
   private ObservableCollection<Model.AcquisitionParameters> acquisitionList = new ObservableCollection<Model.AcquisitionParameters>();

   public ObservableCollection<Model.AcquisitionParameters> AcquisitionList
   {
      get { return acquisitionList; }
      set { acquisitionList = value; OnPropertyChanged("AcquisitionList"); }
   }

   public ObservableCollection<Model.Wavelength> Wavelengths 
   {
      get { return wavelengths; }
      set { wavelengths = value; } 
   }
}
```

View

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Wavelengths}" x:Key="wlList" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AcquisitionList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                  
                  CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
 <DataGrid.Columns>  
   <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Wavelength" Width="SizeToHeader"                                        
                                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Wavelength}"
                                        SelectedValuePath="Value"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource wlList}}"
                                        EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource StandardComboBox}"
                                        ElementStyle="{StaticResource StandardComboBox}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Wavelength

```
public class Wavelength
{
   private double wavelength;

   public double Value 
   {
      get { return wavelength; }
      set { wavelength = Value; }
   }

   public Wavelength(double wl)
   {
      this.wavelength = wl;
   }

   public override string ToString()
   {
      return string.Format("{0:0} nm", wavelength * 1e9);
   }
}
```

Comment: Can SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Wavelength}" & SelectedValuePath="Value" be replaced with SelectedItemBinding? And are you able to post the AcquisitionParameters class?

Comment: I don't understand how are you binding to StaticResource wlList since wList is not available as a resource in your XAML

Comment: I am assuming you have cut a bunch of data out of that xaml?E.g., shortened wavelenghtList to wlList, Omitted the <DataGrid.Columns> XAML markup

Comment: Also SelectedValueBinding with SelectedValuePath means you will be binding the double Value of the selected WaveLength to the WaveLength property on AcquisitionParameters which i am assuming is a Double as well?

Comment: Also,are you sure you are not adding the same Model.AcquisitionParameters object to the collection?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @RagtimeWilly, the acquisitionParameters class contains several properties, one of which is a double one name Wavelength.

Comment: @Michal, the object AcquisitionParameters are added to the collection when the data grid is edited.

Comment: @RagtimeWilly, I also tried to replace SelectedValueBinding by SelectedItemBinding with the same result. I just choose to present one version here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not *really* a problem; believe it or not, it's actually programmed to do this purposely (it's a feature, not a bug).

[`CollectionView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Data.CollectionView(v=vs.110).aspx)s have a [`CurrentItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.currentitem(v=vs.110).aspx) property. If you databind directly to the `CollectionView`, then it keeps the data synchronized. There is an option on every class that inherits from the [`Selector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector(v=vs.110).aspx) class: [`Selector.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem.aspx).

> **true** if the [`SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) is always synchronized with the current item in the [`ItemCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.aspx); **false** if the [`SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) is never synchronized with the current item; **null** if the [`SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) is synchronized with the current item only if the [`Selector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.aspx) uses a [`CollectionView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx). The default value is **null**.

---

The key part is that it defaults to **null**, which synchronizes on `CollectionView`s (which is what you are databinding to). So, just set the property to false on your combobox and you are all set.

Comment: Thanks ! The solution is not really complete as a DataGridComboBoxColumn does not have the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem property. The workaround is to use a style setter : https://wpf.codeplex.com/workitem/8415

Comment: Ah yes, the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is not an actual selector, but the content for that column per row that is generated will contain a `ComoBox`, which is a type of `Selector`. So yes, the complete solution for this specific situation is to make sure to style the generated `ComboBox`.

Comment: @GuillaumeA that links points to the generic page https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wpf.